# structure of Riemannian manifold of isometries from C^n to C^m

Tags: riemannian-geometry

Does anyone know a reference which gives the properties (geodesics, geodesic distance, etc) of the Riemannian manifold of isometries from $\mathbb{C}^n$ into $\mathbb{C}^m$, $m>n$, which map zero to zero?  The metric on the tangent space is inherited from the Frobenius inner product on the set of all matrices.

I'm preferably looking for a reference that I can cite in a compact publication.  (This manifold is relevant to quantum detection theory.)

(Maybe this manifold has a name that someone could provide which would allow me to simply Google it.)

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know of any relevant literature, but I suppose the proof of Wigner's theorem might yield a description of your manifold, at least as a set? In particular, given an inclusion $\mathbb{C}^n \hookrightarrow \mathbb{C}^m$, your manifold will include all isometries on $\mathbb{C}^n$, which by Wigner's theorem is the group generated by $U(n)$ together with the entry-wise complex conjugation operator $C$ on $\mathbb{C}^n$.

Comment: A linear map $T:\mathbb C^n\to \mathbb C^m$ is an isometry if and only if its adjoint $T^*$ is an orthogonal projection. In this way the manifold of isometries can be identified with the manifold of rank $n$ projections, the [Grassmannian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grassmannian).

Comment: You are mistaken.  Consider, for example, the case that $m=n$.  Do you still claim that T is unitary if and only if T* is a projection????  If $m>n$ then $T^*$ does not even map the vector space to itself, so it can't be a projection.

Comment: I got the answer on mathoverflow.  The proper name for this space is a "Stiefel manifold".

Answer (score 1):

Quoting the [answer by Peter Michor](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/130915/reference-request-riemannian-manifold-of-linear-isometries-from-mathbbcn/130925#130925):

> They are called Stiefel manifolds, and are principal $U(n)$-bundles over Grassmann manifolds. They are homogeneous Riemannian manifolds, whereas the Grassmannian are symmetric spaces.

Turns out they [came up a few times](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=stiefel+manifold+is%3Aquestion) on Math.SE.